# How do I reference a specific entry in a YAML block using python?

Tags: python, yaml

I have some YAML data that looks like this:

```
people:
- name: "John"
  age: "20"
  family:
      - mother: "Alice"
        father: "Jeff"
        brother: "Tim"
        sister: "Enid"
- name: "Jake"
  age: "23"
  family:
      - mother: "Meg"
        father: "Rick"
        brother: "Carl"
        sister: "Maddy"
```

How do I print out the name of Jake's mother?

I'm really just trying to print out all family members for each person, but when I make a loop to go through each entry, the code views "name" "age" and "family" as strings.

My code looks like this:

(I have the yaml loaded as a dictionary "persons")

```
    for a in persons["people"]:
        if a == "family":
            for b in persons["people"][a]:
                print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

`people` is a list of dictionaries. If you iterate over it with `for a in persons["people"]`, then in each iteration of the loop, `a` will be a dictionary with the keys `name`, `age`, and `family`. You're looking for the entry where `name` is `Jake`, so:

```
for a in persons["people"]:
    if a["name"] == "Jake":
        ...
```

For reasons that are unclear from your question, `family` is a list of dictionaries, with only a single item in the list in each of your examples. You want the value of the key `mother` from this dictionary, which gets us:

```
for a in persons["people"]:
    if a["name"] == "Jake":
        mother_name = a["family"][0]["mother"]
```

---

If you have control over the format of the data, consider making `family` a single dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries:

```
people:
- name: "John"
  age: "20"
  family:
    mother: "Alice"
    father: "Jeff"
    brother: "Tim"
    sister: "Enid"
- name: "Jake"
  age: "23"
  family:
    mother: "Meg"
    father: "Rick"
    brother: "Carl"
    sister: "Maddy"
```

With that data structure, your code becomes:

```
for a in persons["people"]:
    if a["name"] == "Jake":
        mother_name = a["family"]["mother"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('./file.yml') as file:
        people = yaml.full_load(file)
        for person in people["people"]:
            print(f"{person['name']} parents: ")
            family = person["family"][0]
            for role, name in family.items():
                print(role + ": " + name)

            print("")
```

The output will be

```
John parents: 
mother: Alice
father: Jeff
brother: Tim
sister: Enid

Jake parents: 
mother: Meg
father: Rick
brother: Carl
sister: Maddy
```